# Check if server is running and copy files using a batch script

Tags: tomcat, batch-file

I am required to copy files from one location to another within Tomcat server. The copying has to be done after checking if the server is running.

I have written a piece of script in the startup.bat file, but I am required to check the status of the server before copying.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the availability of a page served by the server, in a batch file, with [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/):

```
curl -sf http://www.google.de > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 echo "Server offline ...""
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo "Server online ..."
```

To check the "real" status of the Tomcat server you, you will have to use [JMX](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/monitoring.html).